# Hashing function to distribute over n values (with a twist)

Tags: algorithm, hash

I was wondering if there are any hashing functions to distribute input over n values. The distribution should of course be fairly uniform. But there is a twist. with small changes of n, few elements should get a new hash. Optimally it should split all k uniformly over n values and if n increases to n+1 only k/n-k/(n+1) values would have to move to uniformly distribute in the new hash. Obviously having a hash which simply creates uniform values and then mod it would work, but that would move a lot of hashes to fill the new node. The goal here is that as few values as possible falls into a new bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose 2^{n-1} < N <= 2^n. Then there is a standard trick for turning a hash function H that produces (at least) n bits into one that produces a number from 0 to N.

1. Compute H(v).
2. Keep just the first n bits.
3. If that's smaller than N, stop and output it. Otherwise, start from the top with H(v) instead of v.

Some properties of this technique:

- You might worry that you have to repeat the loop many times in some cases. But actually the expected number of loops is at most 2.
- If you bump up N and n doesn't have to change, very few things get a new hash: only those ones that had exactly N somewhere in their chain of hashes. (Of course, identifying *which* elements have this property is kind of hard -- in general it may require rehashing every element!)
- If you bump up N and n does have to change, about half of the elements have to be rebucketed. But this happens more and more rarely the bigger N is -- it is an *amortized* O(1) cost on each bump.

**Edit** to add an additional comment about the "have to rehash everything" requirement: One might consider modifying step 3 above to "start from the top with the first n bits of H(v)" instead. This reduces the problem with identifying which elements need to be rehashed -- since they'll be in the bucket for the hash of N -- though I'm not confident the resulting hash will have quite as good collision avoidance properties. It certainly makes the process a bit more fragile -- one would want to prove something special about the choice of H (that the bottom few bits aren't "critical" to its collision avoidance properties somehow).

Here is a simple example implementation in Python, together with a short `main` that shows that most strings do not move when bumping normally, and about half of strings get moved when bumping across a 2^n boundary. Forgive me for any idiosyncracies of my code -- Python is a foreign language.

```
import math

def ilog2(m): return int(math.ceil(math.log(m,2)))

def hash_into(obj, N):
    cur_hash = hash(obj)
    mask = pow(2, ilog2(N)) - 1
    while (cur_hash & mask) >= N:
        # seems Python uses the identity for its hash on integers, which
        # doesn't iterate well; let's use literally any other hash at all
        cur_hash = hash(str(cur_hash))
    return cur_hash & mask

def same_hash(obj, N, N2):
    return hash_into(obj, N) == hash_into(obj, N2)

def bump_stat(objs, N):
    return len([obj for obj in objs if same_hash(obj, N, N+1)])

alphabet = [chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)]
ascending = alphabet + [c1 + c2 for c1 in alphabet for c2 in alphabet]

def main():
    print len(ascending)
    print bump_stat(ascending, 10)
    print float(bump_stat(ascending, 16))/len(ascending)
# prints:
# 702
# 639
# 0.555555555556
```

Comment: Hmm, I have some trouble implementing this. Lets say N is 10, that makes n 4 (2^3 = 8 < 10 < 2^4 = 16). I then compute H(v), in this case with Pythons built in hashing function, returning a 64 bit hash. I keep only the first 4 bits (keeping in mind that this turns some negatives positive). However the stack blows as the hash of H(v) isn't necessarily any smaller than than the hash of v. Did you have a certain H in mind?

Comment: Did some more testing and after shifting H(v) right once (again turning some negatives positive) for each run it seems to work. I think it might have something to do with how Python does hashing and negative numbers (had to do a workaround to actually get the n first bits and not have the number turn negative on me.)

Comment: Did even more testing and your third property seems to be wrong. In my test with 1000 entries going from 16 to 17 nodes ended up with 945 changes. And going from 32 to 33 nodes gave me 973 changes. So it seems to actually be closer to all the data has to rebucket.

Comment: @PMunch I think you must have misunderstood something really serious. You should not be blowing your stack with this (there shouldn't even need to be any recursion). I'm not sure what your comment about "turn some negatives positive" means, but we should be talking about unsigned numbers here -- no negatives.

Comment: @PMunch Ah, I bet the culprit here is Python's (kind of beautiful) choice of hash function for integers: namely, the identity function. Use basically any other hash instead and things will work better; e.g. `hash(str(x))`. Python isn't my strongest language, but hang tight and I'll post some code soon with some analysis.

Comment: I was simply using recursion instead of your while loop so in your case I would probably be stuck in an infinite loop instead. Python abstracts away the whole deal with unsigned numbers unfortunately (try bin(-100)). Python isn't really my strong suit either, was just what I happened to have open at the time. As for the turning of negative numbers I was choosing the n MSB not the n LSB as you are doing, that's what caused the issues. Thanks for the algorithm by the way, works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you add a node, you will want it to fill up, so you will actually want k/(n+1) elements to move from their old nodes to the new one.

That is easily accomplished:

Just generate a hash value for each key as you normally would. Then, to assign key k to a node in [0,N):

```
Let H(k) be the hash of k.

int hash = H(k);
for (int n=N-1;n>0;--n) {
   if ((mix(hash,n) % (i+1))==0) {
      break;
   }
}

//put it in node n
```

So, when you add node node 1, it steals half the items from node 0.
When you add node 2, it steals 1/3 of the items from the previous 2 nodes.
And so on...

EDIT:  added the mix() function, to mix up the hash differently for every n -- otherwise you get non-uniformities when n is not prime.